# Существует ли аналог форматированного вывода и ввода в c++?

Tags: c++, строки

В Си есть функция форматированного ввода и вывода scanf и printf, которые не работают с std::string. Есть ли какие-нибудь схожие функции в c++, работающие со строками, а не массивами символов? Например, если вводится строка формата "name surname age", как сразу присвоить эти значеня строковым и целым переменным s, s1, n соответственно?

Comment: Нужно сделать это без "cin"

Comment: Тогда зачем вам `string`? Работайте в C. Вас же не удивляет отсутствие функции, вычисляющей, скажем, квадратный корень прямо из строкового представления?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

std::string можно преобразовать в char* и использовать с printf/scanf. Для этого есть метод c_str. Вот пример:

```
std::string s = "something";
printf("%s\n", s.c_str());
```

Comment: Для ввода этот метод тоже работает?

Answer (score 4):

В `c++` для ввода-вывода используются потоки `cin`/`cout`, которые можно использовать для этих целей.

```
std::string name;
std::string surname;
int age;

std::cout >> name >> surname >> age;
```

Аналогом `sscanf`/`sprintf` служат `stringstream:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "name surname 666";

std::string name;
std::string surname;
int age;

ss >> name >> surname >> age;
```

Если очень хочется именно `scanf`/`printf`, то нужно конвертировать `std::string` в `const char *`.

```
std::string name = "name";
printf("Name = %s\n", name.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообше то для форматированного ввода и вывода существуют очень удобные средства _ `манипуляторы` из заголовочного файла `<iomanip>`, а также обьекты и методы классов ostream и istream. Лучше  применените манипуляторы

Answer (score 0):

Для форматированного вывода также существуют такие решения: библиотека boost::format ([тут](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/format/doc/format.html)); для библиотеки Qt (а именно класса QString ([тут](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg) и далее)) реализован форматированный вывод; библиотека [fmt](http://fmtlib.net/Text%20Formatting.html); даже есть proposal на соответствующую тему в стандартную библиотеку (основанный, видимо, на [последней](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-proposals/4wOU-1_3D0A/xiNQSmO1CAAJ)).
См. еще [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/318962/)